# What is Rust equivalent of 'pip show package' in python?

Tags: rust

I am looking for a way to identify details of dependencies/crates in Rust. In python, to find the details of an installed package, you can use -

for example - `pip show pandas` will result something like this -

```
Name: pandas
Version: 1.2.4
Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics
Home-page: https://pandas.pydata.org
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: pytz, python-dateutil, numpy
Required-by:
```

Is there an equivalent in Rust where I can get all the details of a crate in terminal?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not by default but there is utility that you need [cargo-show](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-show)

Example output for 'cargo show --dependencies rand':

```
id: rand
name: rand
description: Random number generators and other randomness functionality.

documentation: https://docs.rs/rand
homepage: https://rust-random.github.io/book
repository: https://github.com/rust-random/rand
max_version: 0.8.3
downloads: 64407910
license: None
created: 2015-02-03T06:17:14.147783+00:00
updated: 2021-01-26T08:50:46.191427+00:00
dependencies:
rand_core ^0.6.0
libc ^0.2.22 (opt)
log ^0.4.4 (opt)
packed_simd_2 ^0.3.4 (opt)
rand_chacha ^0.3.0 (opt)
rand_hc ^0.3.0 (opt)
serde ^1.0.103 (opt)
bincode ^1.2.1 (dev)
rand_hc ^0.3.0 (dev)
rand_pcg ^0.3.0 (dev)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for